# AWS S3 - Eventual Consistency for PUTS and DELETES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When data in S3 is replicated in multiple regions , I believe it will take time to propagate. For example , if I update an object in North America East region and assuming the data isn't yet propagated to Asia region and if there are 2 calls to access the data - one in NA and other in Asia , will call to NA return new data vs call to Asia returning old data?

I heard in acloudguru lecture , that no one will receive corrupted data , but i believe the scenario that I had listed above is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-Region Replication (CRR) is an eventually consistent process.  There will be a time delay between the source receiving an object, and the destination receiving the object.  In cases of large objects, [it can take hours](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-and-other-bucket-configs.html#replica-and-lifecycle).

It is likely that when acloudguru was talking about corrupted objects, they were referring to the actual data within the objects being the same once replication completed, and not anything tied to the time it takes to replicate.

Comment: Thanks @nicholas.hauschild! Will both the regions return different versions of the object while replication is in progress?  Also does the replication within availability zones take time as well , which means there is a possibility of returning different versions of the object while accessing the same region?